# How to isolate j?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

can anyone explain me how to isolate the **j** variable please?

$$q = \frac{1 - (1 + j)^{-n}}{j} p $$

TIA

Comment: If you are looking for an exact formula, no, I cannot, apart from $n=1$ to $3$, and it is already paonful at $n=2$.

Comment: So, is it impossible to simplify this?

Comment: Essentially impossible. There is a totally useless expression involving special functions. Of course there are good numeriical algorithms for approximating $y$. There are even good *approximate formulas*, that would work for the reasonable "interest rate" types of $y$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, can you reference any?

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at searching, and only have dim memory of seeing specialized formulas (as opposed to general methods such as Newton-Raphson). Sorry, I am not good at searching, and only have dim memory of seeing specialized formulas (as opposed to general methods such as Newton-Raphson).

Comment: I've found a good link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html

Comment: Good. I was thinking of special purpose estimates, designed for interest calculation. Newton Method is general purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved exactly ("isolating $j$") only under very special circumstances. If $n > 4$ it is probably hopeless (and for $n = 3$ or 4 the exact solution will turn out to be a horrible mess).